# Launch Nautilus from command line: warnings and errors

Tags: nautilus, malware

I am trying to understand why this suddenly gives me error messages.  I have always launched nautilus from the command line and it has always worked. Suddenly I started getting an error message.  I see other posts where people suggest a way to suppress the error message but I am wondering who can explain **why** the sudden change in behavior.  There were no updates installed. Here is the message:

```
Nautilus-Share-Message: 11:57:27.707: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
```

Again, I am interested in ***why*** this suddenly started happening, not merely "fixing" the error message by creating a folder.  Why was that folder not needed before??

Comment: You may be interested in the source code: https://github.com/GNOME/nautilus

Comment: Did you recently remove `samba`?  That message fails because the `net usershare info` cannot read `/var/lib/samba/usershares`

Comment: Nope.  I don't even know what samba is and I have not removed anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because of:

1. You have installed `nautilus-share` package
2. You have removed the `samba` package

Clues:

- https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=net+usershare+info&literal=1&page=1&perpkg=1

To fix:

- reinstall both packages by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus-share samba`

Comment: I didn't install the nautilus-share package between the evening when the command worked and the morning where it produced the error.

Also, I don't know anything about samba, so I am not sure how I could have accidentally deleted it.